# get the list of elements using value

Tags: python, python-2.7

I need some help with my code, I cant be able to find out how I can get the elements I want when I'm using the index of value to get each element from the array.

Here is the output for the `prog_id`:

```
22:24:21 T:2192  NOTICE: 3046
22:24:21 T:2192  NOTICE: 3174
22:24:21 T:2192  NOTICE: 3302
22:24:21 T:2192  NOTICE: 3430
22:24:21 T:2192  NOTICE: 3558
22:24:21 T:2192  NOTICE: 3686
22:24:21 T:2192  NOTICE: 3814
```

Here is the values for each element you could get from the array:

```
>>>> 0 22:24:21 T:2192  NOTICE: 3046
>>>> 1 22:24:21 T:2192  NOTICE: 3174
>>>> 2 22:24:21 T:2192  NOTICE: 3302
>>>> 3 22:24:21 T:2192  NOTICE: 3430
>>>> 4 22:24:21 T:2192  NOTICE: 3558
>>>> 5 22:24:21 T:2192  NOTICE: 3686
>>>> 6 22:24:21 T:2192  NOTICE: 3814
```

Here is the output values for the `prog_index`:

```
22:24:21 T:2192  NOTICE: 1
22:24:21 T:2192  NOTICE: 3
22:24:21 T:2192  NOTICE: 5
22:24:21 T:2192  NOTICE: 6
```

Here is what I want to achieve:

```
22:24:21 T:2192  NOTICE: 3174
22:24:21 T:2192  NOTICE: 3430
22:24:21 T:2192  NOTICE: 3686
22:24:21 T:2192  NOTICE: 3814
```

Here is the code:

```
program_index_ = list()

if current_program_length >= 30:
    program_index = self.program_index
program_index_.append(program_index)

program_button = [elem.control for elem in self.program_buttons]
progId = list()
posX = list()
posY = list()

for elem in program_button:
    progId.append(elem.getId())
    posX.append(elem.getX())
    posY.append(elem.getY())
progId = map(str, progId)
posX = map(str, posX)
posY = map(str, posY)


for pos_X, pos_Y, prog_id, prog_index in izip_longest(posX, posY, progId, program_index_, fillvalue=''):
    if int(pos_X) == 375:
       print prog_id
```

I have tried this:

```
prog_index = prog_id[test_index]
print prog_index
```

It give me an error: TypeError: string indices must be integers, not str

I guess that I have done it wrong.

Can you please tell me how I can use the variable `prog_id` to get the value from `prog_index` so I could to search for each element from the array using with the value?

Comment: Very unclear what you're asking. Where is come from the first output? The first output above is a list, file lines or a dict? What is `prog_id`?

Comment: @felipsmartins the `prog_id` is a list of strings that I stored in the list. I want to search for each of string from the array using the value from the variable `prog_index`. I have tried `prog_index = prog_id[test_index]`, but it give me an error. Any idea?

Comment: In your code `progId` is a list and `progid` is of type `str` (look in for loop).

Comment: @Zetys yeah I know that, but I want to know how I could use `progId` with the `prog_index` to get the index of strings from the array?   i am sure you will know how to do this and I am sure you know what I am talking about.

Comment: any idea??????????????????

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not sure if I understand your question. It sounds like you know the index for the elements you're trying to get from the list and you want an output of each element based on that index 1, 3, 5, 6. If so, this code should work for you:

```
data = ['22:24:21 T:2192  NOTICE: 3046',
'22:24:21 T:2192  NOTICE: 3174',
'22:24:21 T:2192  NOTICE: 3302',
'22:24:21 T:2192  NOTICE: 3430',
'22:24:21 T:2192  NOTICE: 3558',
'22:24:21 T:2192  NOTICE: 3686',
'22:24:21 T:2192  NOTICE: 3814']

index_get = [1,3,5,6]
data2 = [data[i] for i in index_get]
print (data2)
```

Output:

```
['22:24:21 T:2192  NOTICE: 3174', '22:24:21 T:2192  NOTICE: 3430', '22:24:21 T:2192  NOTICE: 3686', '22:24:21 T:2192  NOTICE: 3814']
```

Comment: thank you very much for this that is what I asking for. Can you please convert your code to my code as it make things more easy for me? thanks!!

Comment: @user3761625 My code answers your original question. If I try to sort out your code and integrate my answer with it, it will bring up a couple of other questions which I would have to address. Then, this post will become very confusing. What you should do is to mark this answer as the correct answer to your current question, then post and other question which will focus on the additional difficulties you may have.